# Wordpress blank pages issue

Tags: wordpress, migration

5 years ago I used a wordpress site v3.2 w/ sqlite *hack method*, today I remove all the files and install a clean wordpress-4.2.4 w/ mySQL.. The problem was how to 'carry' the 693records from v3.2.. Now the problem is when I clicked an anchor link to do something example at POSTS search searchbox I endup with an empty page..

for example when Im on All posts and press search button on right, end up with a white page at :
http://www.z.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=123&post_status=all&post_type=post&_wpnonce=0f18ec3fe1&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1

or when editing a post and click update button, the post updated but end up with http://z.com/post.php and the white page :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

was template fault, update it and working